# How early do I need to arrive at Most na Soči for a space on the car train

Tags: trains, public-transport, tips-and-tricks, automobiles, slovenia

Slovenian Railways run a car-transport train service from Most na Soči to Bohinjska Bistrica, called Motorail. This lets you skip a lot of driving around the hills, and is reportedly a fun journey through interesting valleys in itself.

However, [as the English language page says simply to buy tickets on the train](http://www.slo-zeleznice.si/en/passenger-transport/timetable/motorail), I was wondering how likley it is if I arrive the required 10 minutes before departure that I will atually get on the train, or if it might be full. I'm planning on doing this for the 10:35 departure on a high-season (July) Saturday, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I can't provide a general answer (so anyone who lives locally or otherwise knows better should still answer), however I can provide a single experience:

Arriving almost exactly 30 minutes before scheduled departure, we were the last vehicle to be permitted to board the train. Some 6-10 cars were turned away, and presumably made the drive over the mountain passes themselves. This may not be typically however, because there was a wedding party travelling on the train, taking at least a mini-coach as well as 10+ private cars. Of course, it is also possible there is a wedding party doing this every weekend in the summer. No vehicles attempted to board at Podbrdo, but then non would have been able to either.

### Useful observations for future travellers

- what with the queueing, then the fairly lengthy boarding process for cars, I'm not sure how much time is saved between driving over the pass to Bohinj
- Most na Soči station is not actually in Most na Soči. It's a little bit futher down the Idrica river, across the river from the main road.
- Most na Soči is situated on an amazing coloured lake. If you have time, stop for breakfast or a coffee there.